# Creating affinity from arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say... there are 5 persons `A0, A1, A2, A3, A4` each one has a list of preferences:

```
{
 'A0': [3, 1, 4, 2],
 'A1': [2, 3, 0, 4],
 'A2': [4, 3, 0, 1],
 'A3': [0, 2, 4, 1],
 'A4': [2, 0, 1, 3]
}
```

So that `'A0': [3, 1, 4, 2]` means `A0`'s favourite person is `A3` and less favourite is `A2`. I want to create a list (or dictionary, no matters what) with the optimal recommendations of pairs. For example: it can be seen that `A0` and `A3` matches pretty well, so that would be a pair. How can I do this?

Comment: How would you translate "matches pretty well" into code?  What would be the rest of the "optimal recommendations" for this sample data, and why?

Comment: @ScottHunter they must have a good affinity. But that's what I'm asking for, because I do not know how to code it. Each list is created from Better Affinity to Lower Affinity.

Comment: Can you *define* what "affinity" means in this context?  You say A0 & A3 "match pretty well", but A3 ranked A0 *last*.

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry it was a mistake. Now it's corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below. the code calculate the average affinity between Ax to Ay

```
import itertools

d = {
 'A0': [3, 1, 4, 2],
 'A1': [2, 3, 0, 4],
 'A2': [4, 3, 0, 1],
 'A3': [0, 2, 4, 1],
 'A4': [2, 0, 1, 3]
}
pairs = list(itertools.combinations(d.keys(),r=2))
affinity_list = []
for p in pairs:
  affinity1 = d[p[0]].index(int(p[1][-1]))
  affinity2 = d[p[1]].index(int(p[0][-1]))
  avg = (affinity1 + affinity2) /2
  affinity_list.append((p,avg))

affinity_list = sorted(affinity_list,key = lambda x:x[1],reverse=False)
print(affinity_list)
```

output

```
[(('A0', 'A3'), 0.0), (('A2', 'A4'), 0.0), (('A2', 'A3'), 1.0), (('A0', 'A1'), 1.5), (('A0', 'A4'), 1.5), (('A1', 'A2'), 1.5), (('A1', 'A3'), 2.0), (('A0', 'A2'), 2.5), (('A1', 'A4'), 2.5), (('A3', 'A4'), 2.5)]
```